# Usar Objeto en otro Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, poo, objeto

Como puedo usar un objeto declarado en mi formulario 1 para usarlo en mi form2.
En mi formulario 1 el usuario ingresa unos datos que se almacenan en un objeto declarado en el form1.cs  y yo quiero operar ese objeto en mi formulario 2. Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tienes 2 formas que se me ocurran en el momento, si subis codigo te puedo ayudar mejor.

1_VARIABLE ESTATICA = crea una variable estatica en una clase,o dentro de tu mismo form, asi desde cualquier lado que la llames siempre tiene el ultimo valor que le asignaste, por ejemplo si queres llamarla desde FORM2 y esa variable esta dentro de tu FORM1 seria asi **FORM1.staticVAR**, simple, como cualquier otra clase, pero sin instanciarla.

2_PASARLA POR PARAMETRO = al crear tu FORM2 desde tu FORM1 pasasela por parametro en su contructor, ejemplo **new FORM2(VARIABLE).show();**
y desde el contructor de tu FORM2 agregas que se va a pasar una variable, ejemplo:

```
private object obj;
public FORM2(object obj)
{
    this.obj = obj;
}
```

Espero que se entienda y te ayude, de todas formas, si subis codigo a tu pregunta es mas probable que se interprete mejor la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Una consulta, lo que sugieres en ambos casos no genera "tight coupling" entre las clases `form1` y `form2`?

Comment: Hola!, No estaria seguro si genera una 'alta dependencia' entre clases, de todas formas, no se si la pregunta se basa a que te parece que eso es mala practica o solo curiosidad. De mi parte tube que buscar que significaba lo que me dijiste por que no estoy seguro si lo escuche nombrar. Disculpa